# IOKit and TrustedBSD policy

Tags: macos, linker, kernel, iokit, kernel-extension

How can I use the MAC policies from TrustedBSD inside an IOKit kernel extension?

I already have a working IOKit extension and I would like to add  some policies to it.

For testing, I wrote two dummy extensions, one using IOKit and a generic one.
The generic extension is working flawlessly, whilst the IOKit one is generating a link error for the symbols `mac_policy_register` and `mac_policy_unregister`.

```
$ sudo kextutil -tn /tmp/MACPolicy.kext
kxld[com.Test.MACPolicy]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
kxld[com.Test.MACPolicy]:   mac_policy_register(mac_policy_conf*, unsigned int*, void*)
kxld[com.Test.MACPolicy]:   mac_policy_unregister(unsigned int)
Link failed (error code 5).
Check library declarations for your kext with kextlibs(8).

$ sudo kextlibs -v 6 -undef-symbols /tmp/MACPolicy.kext
Kext user-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Kext kernel-space log filter changed from 0xff2 to 0xfff.
Kext library architecture set to x86_64.
Kext library architecture is x86_64 (unchanged).
For all architectures:
    com.apple.kpi.iokit = 15.4
    com.apple.kpi.libkern = 15.4

For x86_64:
    2 symbols not found in any library kext:
    __Z21mac_policy_unregisterj
    __Z19mac_policy_registerP15mac_policy_confPjPv
```

I already added the specified libraries to my `Info.plist`, as well as `com.apple.kpi.dsep`, `com.apple.kpi.unsupported`, `com.apple.kpi.mach` or any combination of those, with no success.

All the information I could found about this was this [thread on the darwin-kernel](http://www.lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-kernel/2013/Jun/msg00003.html) discussion list.

I am targeting OS X 10.11 for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how the missing symbols are mangled as if they were C++ functions, but the functions in questions are actually plain C functions. This means when you're calling them from C++, they're using a declaration that's missing the `extern "C"` linkage specifier. The MAC headers don't take into account C++, so when including them from a .cpp file, you need to wrap them in an `extern "C"` block explicitly, like so:

```
extern "C" {
#include <security/mac_policy.h>
}
```

If your `#include` is in a mixed C/C++ header file, you'll need to make it conditional on C++ compilation using `#ifdef __cplusplus` as usual.

Comment: I also found this right now on this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702967/mount-approval-callback-on-mac-os-x#comment53763572_27754917)

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware, despite on fact that this functionality **was official added**, based on  *OS X v10.11 API Diffs* [Kernel Changes for Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_11/Objective-C/Kernel.html)

[image]

**Unfortunately**, started from *High Sierra (10.13)* MAC policy API was totally closed for third party developers. Apple deleted all references for `mac_policy_register`,`mac_policy_unregister`, `mac_policy_conf`, `mac_policy_ops` and other main MAC policy parts from own documentations.

Comment: Where do you get this info from?

Comment: Native "include" no longer works started from High Sierra (10.13), “mac_policy.h” header was deleted from SDK 10.13. Any information about MAC policy has been removed in Xcode 9 documentation and from Apple developer portal.